# A discrete function and its rate of oscillation

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Consider a function

> $y[n]= \cos[w  n ]$, where $n$ is an integer.

I have to prove that this signal will have highest rate of oscillation at $w = \pi$.
I was thinking I can take the derivatives (of rate of oscillation) and set condition of maxima, but the variable is a discrete variable and not a continuous one.

How do I actually prove this?

**Update**

This is what I observe:

at  $w = 0$ all samples will have value 1 and
at $w = \pi$ samples will have positive and negative values in succession- highest rate of oscillation

Please [[see this, page number 16]](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=CTw6GoBh-vkC&lpg=PA1&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=true), but they have not proved it.

Here is the corresponding page from the book ([Digital Signal Processing: Principles, Algorithms and Applications (3rd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133737624) ):

[image] 
[image]

As can be seen they have just verified, and not proved. I want to prove this.

Comment: Why did you change to $\cos?$ It doesn't change anything much except to make it $\frac \pi 2$ instead of $0$ in my last sentence.

Comment: In my original question , it is actually cos

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "maximum oscillation"? If the range of $y$, it will be $(-1,1)$ for almost any choice of $w$.  If by a local maximum, it isn't a function of $w$, but of $n$.  If $\theta=0, y[n]$ will always be $0$ for $w=\pi$, certainly not a maximum oscillation.

Comment: Maximum oscillation means highest rate of oscillation

Comment: @gpuguy:  $3\pi$ will work just as well, as will $5 \pi \ldots$

Comment: please see [page 16 here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=CTw6GoBh-vkC&lpg=PA1&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=true)

Comment: @gpuguy:  It doesn't let me Look Inside

Comment: the book is: Digital Signal Processing, by Proakis et al.

Comment: I have posted the relevant page